# Order of evaluation of functions used as parameters to member constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Let's assume a class:

```
struct S {
    Obj1 o1;
    Obj2 o2;

    S() : o2( fn2() ), o1( fn1(), fn3() ) {}
};
```

What is guaranteed to be sequenced-before in this case?  o1() is sequenced-before o2().   fn1() and fn3() are sequenced-before o1(), fn2() is sequenced-before o2().  The question is the sequenced-before of the fns.  As I understand it, fn1() and fn3() may be done in an unspecified order.  Are fn1() and fn3() guaranteed to be sequenced-before fn2()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**[intro.execution]/12**](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5) A *full-expression* is...
>
> (12.3) — an *init-declarator* (Clause 11) or a *mem-initializer* (15.6.2), including the constituent expressions of the initializer...
>
> [**[intro.execution]/16**](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#9) Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

Thus, the invocation of `o1( fn1(), fn3() )`, together with all its sub-expressions and side effects, is sequenced before the invocation of `o2( fn2() )`.

In case you are still not convinced, there's this non-normative note in [**[class.base.init]/7**](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#7):

> [ *Note:* The initialization performed by each *mem-initializer* constitutes a full-expression (4.6). Any expression in a *mem-initializer* is evaluated as part of the full-expression that performs the initialization. *—end note* ]

Comment: You've probably meant `o2(fn2())` is seqdB4 everything else.

Comment: No, I have not. Why?

Comment: No, they are not. "**[class.base.init]/13** In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order: ... Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
(again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*)."

Comment: Clarification question: does this apply equally to c++11 and 17? (Wasn’t something around this changed in 17 to plug a hole where the compiler would be able to execute fn1, 2, and 3 in arbitrary order?)

Comment: @AndreKostur - there was a change related to some particular cases (e.g `E1 << E2` in C++17 is guaranteed to evaluate `E1` before `E2`, which wasn't the case previously).    But the order of initialisation done in a constructor hasn't changed, and the order of evaluation of function arguments is still unspecified (e.g. in `o1(f1(), f2())`, the order of calling `f1()` and `f2()` is still unspecified).